# CORS Problem in an Angular/.net core webapi application

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular 8 and .net core 3.0.1 trying to learn something about the development of Webapplications.
Unfortunatly I have some issue when trying to call some data from my .net core webapi to the Angular framework application. In the browser console I recieve the error regarding CORS Access.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/api/user/pagewise/1/10' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I thought I had activated Cors in my webapi Startup.cs:

```cs
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {   
           _connectionString ="XXX";

           services.AddCors( opt => 
               {
                   opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                   c => c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowAnyHeader());
               })
               ;
           services.AddControllers();
           services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
           .AddDbContext<ApiContext>(
               opt => opt.UseNpgsql(_connectionString));
       } 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataSeed seed)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseCors("CorsePolice");
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

           }
           app.UseCors("CorsePolice");

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();

           app.UseRouting();

           app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllers();
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
               endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("CorsPolicy");
           });
  }
```

But it seems to be not working. Is there some different way of using Cors in a .net core 3.0.1 WebApi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be you have use `CorsPolicy` in `opt.AddPolicy()`. But you are using `CorsePolice` in `app.UseCors()`. So use like `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the typo.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons why you are getting CORS error:-
1. use proper header into the request to the API from the angular side 
2. may be possible that you are not allowing the CORS from the backend side

To resolve use:- 
1. use allow-cross-origin in angular 
2. Try using a cors plugin in chrome browser I guess your problem will go.

also, try to use API through postman it will make you sure which side is the problem

these are some problems I faced and the ways I resolved. I am not sure it will definitely help you but give it a try might help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed is the request working if using Postman. I also tried the "Allow CORS" plugin in firefox. It does make the request working. But shoudn't the request run in every situation, even with out such plugin installed?  Also I am not sure how to add  "allow-cross-origin in angular ".

Comment: Did you tried to add and remove headers in angular?

Comment: httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Allow': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
    })
  };

Comment: return this.http
      .post<any>(url,body, { headers: this.httpOptions.headers });

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed mistake was a typo in CorsPolic(y,e)

Comment: haha ok .... you solved your problem i am happy